# How can Darwin frameworks be provided to `cc_library` or `cc_binary` rules?

Tags: bazel, nix

When compiling a binary from Tensorflow on Darwin, I got the following error: 
`ld: framework not found IOKit`.

I used [`rules_nixpkgs`](https://github.com/tweag/rules_nixpkgs) (the way that my team has chosen to provision executables, compilers, etc not natively supported by Bazel) to get a copy of the IOKit framework, and added a `filegroup` target:

```
nixpkgs_package(
    name = "iokit",
    repository = "@nixpkgs",
    attribute_path = "darwin.IOKit",
    build_file_content = """
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
filegroup(
    name = "framework",
    srcs = ["Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit"],
)
cc_library(
    name = "headers",
    hdrs = glob(["Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Headers/*.h"]),
)""",
)
```

adding this to the `srcs` field of the binary target didn't work, since it only allows certain file extensions. Adding a `data` field seemed to have no effect.

Comment: Hi palmer, thanks for your question! I am a bit puzzled though, by what you mean in your second sentence "I nixpkgs to get a copy [...]". It is unclear to me how you are integrating bazel and nix. If you could clarify your setup, that will greatly help someone with expertise in Nix and/or Bazel to answer your question.

Comment: @robert-hensing, thanks for helping make my question clearer. I've added some context around our Bazel and Nix usage.